# How to make a Multi Role for different dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oop

I want to make a role in one login form for different admin users. But when I try to select finance in the dropdown menu I still get to enter the admin dashboard, not the finance dashboard. my db roles are called 'admin' and 'finance'.

This is my login form:

[image]

this is what I have so far:

```
<form method="post" name="login_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="username" alt="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="password" type="password" alt="password" placeholder="Password"  autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <select type="text" class="form-control" name="type" required="">
      <option value="" disabled="" disabled="" selected="true">--Select Role--</option>
      <option value="admin">Admin</option>
      <option value="finance">Finance</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="remember" onclick="myFunction()"><span class="custom-control-label">Show Password</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block button3" ;color: rgb(243, 245, 238) !important;" value="Sign in" id="btn-login" name="btn-login">Log in</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="alert-msg">
  </form>
```

am I missing something?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function(){
    $('form[name="login_form"]').on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var u_username = $(this).find('input[alt="username"]').val();
      var p_password = $(this).find('input[alt="password"]').val();
      // var s_status = 1;

      if (u_username === '' && p_password ===''){
        $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> Required Username and Password!</div>');
      }else{
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'init/controllers/login_process.php',
          data: {
            username: u_username,
            password: p_password
            //status: s_status
         },
         beforeSend:  function(){
           $('#alert-msg').html('');
         }
       })
       .done(function(t){
         if (t == 0){
           $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Incorrect username or password!</div>');
         }else{
           $("#btn-login").html('<img src="assets/images/loading.gif" /> &nbsp; Signing In ...');
           setTimeout(' window.location.href = "documents/index.php"; ',2000);
         }
       });
     }
   });
 });
 </script>
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("password");
   if (x.type === "password") {
     x.type = "text";
   } else {
     x.type = "password";
   }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Where, in your code, do you think it attempts to load the "finance" dashboard?

Comment: Protip: pass a function to `setTimeout` not a string: `setTimeout(() => window.location.href = "documents/index.php", 2000);`

Comment: You have a drop down for role, but never use it.  If it's not needed for the login, that's ok, so in the login callback `.done` you redirect to "documents/index" - but again, no check for which role - I would expect to see that check there, eg if `$("[name=type]").val() == "admin") ... else ...`  (`type` is not a good name btw as it clashes with too many other `type` reserved words).  TBH - I wouldn't expect to see a Role input on a login as the system should know which role I'm in and not let me decide I want to see "admin" if I'm not an admin, maybe your next step?

Comment: Why does your dropdown say "--Select role--" but your question talks about "dashboard"? Shouldn't it be: "--Select dashboard--"? Furthermore you name the select input "type", why? We now have the names "role", "dashboard" and "type" for the same thing. In programming it is important to stay consistent.